# Compare Hash Arrays in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I'm trying to compare and find the difference between two nested hashes with multiple hash arrays within arrays.

What is the best way to go about this comparison? It appears there are no libraries or functions that can help with this..

For example, I want the below two examples of hash a and hash b to be considered equal.

```
pry(main)> a
#⇒ {"197315"=>{:qty=>1,
#              :modifiers=>[{"197323-197319"=>{:qty=>1}},
#                           {"197322-197321"=>{:qty=>1}}]}}

pry(main)> b
#⇒ {"197315"=>{:qty=>1,
#              :modifiers=>[{"197322-197321"=>{:qty=>1}},
#                           {"197323-197319"=>{:qty=>1}}]}}

pry(main)> a == b
#⇒ false

pry(main)> a
#⇒ {"197315"=>{:qty=>1,
#              :modifiers=>[{"197322-197321"=>{
#                :qty=>1,
#                :modifiers=>['2222'=>'33333', '4444'=>'55555']}}, 
#                           {"197323-197319"=>{:qty=>1}}]}}

pry(main)> b
#⇒ {"197315"=>{:qty=>1,
#              :modifiers=>[{"197322-197321"=>{
#                :qty=>1,
#                :modifiers=>['4444'=>'55555', '2222'=>'33333']}},
#                            {"197323-197319"=>{:qty=>1}}]}}

pry(main)> a == b
#⇒ false
```

Comment: change `:modifiers=>[]` to `:modifiers=>set`?

Comment: In the second example, `['2222'=>'33333', '4444'=>'55555']
 => [{"2222"=>"33333", "4444"=>"55555"}]`. I wasn't sure if you meant to write the hash that way or forget the braces, but either way is of course OK.

Comment: You question is unclear. Do you want to find the differences or ignore such differences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This recursive solution should work with any number of levels of nested arrays and hashes.

**Code**

```
require 'set'

def arr_to_set(o)
  case o
  when Hash
    o.each_with_object({}) { |(k,v),g| g[k] = arr_to_set(v) }
  when Array
    o.map { |e| arr_to_set(e) }.to_set
  else
    o
  end
end
```

**Examples**

*Example 1*

```
a = {"197315"=>{:qty=>1, :modifiers=>[
                           {"197323-197319"=>{:qty=>1}},
                           {"197322-197321"=>{:qty=>1}}
                         ]
               }
    }

b = {"197315"=>{:qty=>1, :modifiers=>[
                           {"197322-197321"=>{:qty=>1}},
                           {"197323-197319"=>{:qty=>1}}
                         ]
               }
    }

arr_to_set(a) == arr_to_set(b)
  #=> true
```

*Example 2*

```
c = {"197315"=>{:qty=>1,
                :modifiers=>[
                  {"197322-197321"=>{ :qty=>1,
                                      :modifiers=>['2222'=>'33333', '4444'=>'55555']
                                    }
                  },
                  {"197323-197319"=>{:qty=>1}
                  }
                ]
              }
    }

d = {"197315"=>{:qty=>1,
                :modifiers=>[
                  {"197322-197321"=>{:qty=>1,
                                     :modifiers=>['4444'=>'55555', '2222'=>'33333']
                                    }
                  },
                  {"197323-197319"=>{:qty=>1}
                  }
                ]
               }
    }

arr_to_set(c) == arr_to_set(d)
  #=> true
```

Comment: echan00, you are welcome. See my edit. I was able to simplify quite a bit.